# A javascript object that is a parent of itself?

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, prototype

I'm writing a scraping and data-entry program to save my mom and her coworkers literally hours worth of mind-numbingly repetitive form submissions.  Everything's been going great until I got to this one onclick function call on a submit button.  The function (we'll call it dataLogger() for security purposes) takes a single input field entry as an argument and then... I have no idea... because it refers to a function that essentially calls it's parent's constructor... like this (with function name swapped out):

```
dataLogger(data) {
   if (parent)
        if (typeof(parent.dataLoggerP) == 'function')
            parent.dataLoggerP(data);
```

So I put a breakpoint at this function and inspected the "dataLogger" object in firebug.  I figured I would just look in the children of the prototype node, see the "dataLoggerP" function of the parent, search for that function definition, and have my problem solved.  But an interesting thing happened.  I would click the `prototype:` node in firebug in the Watch Expressions and see two nodes within it: `constructor: dataLogger(data)`, and `__proto__:`.  I open the `constructor: dataLogger(data)` node only to find that it's a replica of the original dataLogger Object!  And within that one, there's another... and another... to infinity.  It's like an mc escher painting...

I have no idea what's going on or how this is able to work... any insight into this is greatly appreciated..

Comment: Also, I just added `parent` to the watch expressions and could not find a `dataLoggerP(data)` object like the one this function is supposed to call, only a `dataLogger(data)` (has no "P" at the end) object that prototypes itself into infinity again!

Answer (score 1):

`constructor` is the function that created the object. It is not the parent in the inheritance sense. Even better, `parent` is not the parent of the object, it is (unless otherwise defined) parent of the *window* (if you have frames or iframes). This code, if nothing else is defined, should see if the parent window (if it exists) has `dataLoggerP` function (not object), and if it does, execute it. If there is no parent window, or if it does not have `dataLoggerP` function defined on it, nothing happens, there is no error, because it's all wrapped in checks.

Comment: well if that's the case why is `dataLoggerP` nowhere to be found when I do a global search in firebug?  This function works too... it submits the data to some kind of database, but since I can't find the function `dataLoggerP()`, I have no way of knowing what happens to data.  Where might I likely find `dataLoggerP()` in this scenario?

Comment: Sorry, without more detail that is as much as I can say. If it exists, it will be on `parent`. If you don't have another `parent` variable, that is `window.parent`. Check inside the function if `window.parent === parent`. Also, I am not familiar with Firebug that much (I am a Chrome kind of person), and I don't know about global search. Try looking through all JavaScript and HTML files that are loaded for your page, in your Network tab. If it's not there, it most likely does not exist (it *could* be hidden somewhere, decrypted and eval'd, but that is unlikely).

Comment: Today was the first time I used the firefox debugger and I've only used chrome's before it... definitely worth checking out if you haven't, it's all around faster with more features.  I just checked inside `parent` and there is no `dataLoggerP()`.  If it was hidden is there any way I can unhide it and access it's contents?

Comment: Also do you know where I can find more information about encrypting and decrypting blocks of code in javascript?  I can't wrap my head around how the browser would know, for instance, that `dataLoggerP()` is a call to an encrypted function and so needs to be decrypted before running... I mean it looks like a totally normal function call.. where's the magic happening?

Comment: As I said, that (encrypted code) almost never happens, so I don't think that's what's happening... but browser wouldn't know it was encrypted, some other piece of code would have to decrypt it and eval it before you could call it. Try to set a breakpoint in `dataLogger` and see what `parent` is there, and whether it has `dataLoggerP` or not. It can't be hidden; it's there or it isn't. Looking at any other time is not really worth it. Other than that, not knowing anything about your code other than what you wrote, that's as much as I can say.

Comment: Yeah I understand there's not much to say with what I gave you.  I just tried your advice and `parent`, even in the function, does not have a `dataLoggerP()` property.  Even more weird... I added `parent.dataLoggerP` to my watch list and it's undefined... and yet it still satisfies the condition `if (typeof(parent.dataLoggerP) == 'function')` because it goes on to call `parent.dataLoggerP(data)` right after successfully.  I knew javascript had many features to make it super versatile but I didn't know it could do magic as well?  Very cool. :P

Answer (score 0):

Its just a [circular reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference). For a simple example, examine this object in the console

```
var obj = {}
obj.x = obj;
```

This particular example you found is true for any function in javascript. All javascript functions have a `prototype` property, which is an object with a `constructor` field that points back to the original function.